# how to add date picker to form_input

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

im trying to add jquery datepicker to the input field, but im not accomplishing this. here is my code

```
       <div class="field_row clearfix">
        <?php   
        echo form_label($this->config->item('custom'.$i.'_name').':', 'custom'.$i,array('class'=>'wide')); ?>
        <div class='form_field' onclick="test()" id='datepickers'>
            <?php echo form_input(array(
                'name'=>'custom'.$i,
                'id'=>'custom'.$i,
                'value'=>$item_arr['custom'.$i])
            );?>

        </div>
    </div>

     function test() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     }
```

this is what i tried with onlcik, but i really like to go it exactly as this example.

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

 $(function() {
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 }
```

Comment: Any console errors? do you have the jQuery library included on the page ?

Comment: where are the script tags around your js code?

Comment: yes the library is included, the error is  items:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined, the id datepicker is there cause it was the 1 method i used, i chose now onclick since i couldn't get it working, i have the tags set, just when i tried to paste the question for some reason i couldnt added it, but i open close <script>

Comment: In your HTML, your div has an ID of 'datepickers'.  In your javascript, you're calling '#datepicker'.  Either change your div ID or change your selecter.  Also add script tags around your javascript function

Answer (score 0):

Spot the differences?

```
    <div class='form_field' onclick="test()" id='datepickers'>
                                                          ^^^

 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
               ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your **datepickers** id is not on an input, its on a div in your case.

You can add up a classname (If you have multiple inputs) to the field that your are generating through CI form helper.

```
<?php echo form_input(array(
          'name'=>'custom'.$i,
          'id'=>'custom'.$i,
           'class' => 'datepicker',
          'value'=>$item_arr['custom'.$i])
    );?>
```

Then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
}
</script>
```

Should work if your datapicker js and css are loaded fine. Always check console for errors, or use firebug.

Comment: thanks it works all i needed to do was add the class to the array, guess i got a lot more to learn here

Comment: You are welcome :-) Keep learning everyday and you will be there.

Answer (score 0):

for best practices use HTML-5 tag date

Date:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date

Comment: that was the 1 thing i tried, but with codeigniter isnt that simply due the way it was build, im currently leaning this framework

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to add the script tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> ....</script>
```

Also add a class value for the input: class="datepicker" :)